# QTreeView selectedIndex issue when mouse is dragged

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview, mouseclick-event, qt-signals

Given below is a code snippet to get selected row(index) on the `QTreeView` and read the associated data.

It works fine. However, if I left click on a row and drag it in to another index, the function outputs index of the first click, but I want to read index of the row when the left mouse is released.

What signal of `QTreeView` do I need to use to read selected index when the mouse click is released?

```
Object::Oject(QVector<QPair<QString, QString> > allItems){ 

        treeView = new QTreeView(Dialog);
         treeView->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("listView"));
         treeView->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 221, 481));

         QStandardItemModel *standardModel = new QStandardItemModel ;
         rootNode = standardModel->invisibleRootItem();

         treeView->setIconSize(QSize(40,30));
         treeView->setDragEnabled(false);
         treeView->setHeaderHidden(true);

         treeView->setModel(standardModel);
         treeView->expandAll();


   QVector< QPair <QString, QString > >::Iterator it;
    for (it=allItems.begin(); it != allItems.end(); it++){
        nItem = new QStandardItem(QString("%1").arg(it->second));
        nItem->setEditable(false);
        nItem->setDragEnabled(false);
        rootNode->appendRow(nItem);
    }

  QObject::connect(treeView, SIGNAL( clicked(const QModelIndex &)), this, SLOT(getSelectedIndexFcn(const QModelIndex &)));
}

void Object::getSelectedIndexFcn(const QModelIndex &index){
    selectedIndexRow = index.row();
    selectedIndexIPaddr = index.data().toString();

}
```

Comment: Have you tried to override mouseReleaseEvent? `http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mouseReleaseEvent`

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use `QTreeWidget` and its signal `itemEntered(QTreeWidgetItem*, int)` or `itemSelectionChanged()`.